# How to search for playlists on Last.fm?

Tags: last.fm

I thought it used to be possible to search for playlists on Last.fm. Specifically, I'd like to be able to search for all playlists that include any given song. But now I can't even figure out how to browse or search playlists at all (not even by title, which I can do directly in Spotify anyway).

Am I missing something? Or is there really no way to search for users' playlists (Spotify playlists ideally) on Last.fm?